# Stop body scrolling in Mobile Safari

Tags: css, scroll, mobile-safari

I'm trying to stop the body of my page from scrolling (at all) while a modal overlay is open.

The modal covers the entire screen (`{position: fixed;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;}`), and it has its own scrolling. However, when I run to the end of the scroll on my modal window, the main window starts scrolling behind it. I've tried everything I can think of to make the body stop scrolling. These things haven't worked:

#### CSS

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: none;
}
#content { /* which contains all the non-modal content of the body */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    position: relative; left: 100%;
}
```

- using iScroll
- blocking the scroll event of window or body
- blocking the touchstart event on body

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're pretty close.

When your modal is open, try this CSS:

```
body{
    overflow:visible;
    max-height:100%; /* or 100px or something smaller than the screen if your viewport isn't set */
    height:100% /* or 100px or something smaller than the screen */
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nope. Still doesn't stop the body from scrolling.

Comment: Hmm.. have you experimented with switching the #content display mode to absolute with a height: 0 when the Modal is up? My concern is this may cause a 'jump' in the content if #content is no longer contributing to the page scrollHeight, but might work.

Comment: Yes, and that does stop scrolling, but it also means scroll position is lost when `#content` has its height returned to initial.

Comment: What about 'caching' the scroll position for #content while it's in that temporary state- when the modal is closed, simply pull the data-scroll attribute (or whatever you call it) and set body ScrollTop to that value?

Comment: Yep—just arrived at this solution myself. What a mess. Thanks!

Comment: Hacks! Glad you found your way out :)